# How to regenerate Session Token on each Ajax request with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP application which has some jQuery and Ajax features in it. I would like to know, how is it possible to regenerate the Session Token - which I'm sending to validate the Ajax request - upon each Ajax request (without loading the page)?

I have more elements on the page which are running multiple Ajax queries, however at this moment they all get the same token. So if someone has the tokey, they can submit a forged request from another form I guess.

Comment: sounds like an http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Generating token on client side makes no sense. You can't trust anything coming from client side, as you don't know if it's your client software which sends the request, or a malicious one.
You must create as many tokens as you have ajax possible requests, and return a new token with each response.

Comment: I did never say that I intend to generate the tokens on the client side. I'd want to generate them on the server side of course, this is the only way to create a session.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. So why don't you generate a different token for each ajax call in your page, and give a new one to replace it, each time an ajax call is made? It implies you store a list of tokens in session on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a CSRF token on server side for each user or each session. You can store it in your database, or in your session. You should send that token to your client, and wait it back with the ajax requests. It will work until your site is not XSS vulnerable...

Btw the first step to secure your application is using the HTTPS protocol...